# How to format multiple exFAT partitions on USB drive?

Tags: mac, usb, disk-utility, partition, exfat

I'm following the instructions in [Creating a bootable Clonezilla dual partition USB device](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10144/Creating-a-bootable-Clonezilla-dual-partition-USB-device.html) but using my Mac laptop running El-Capitan.

I managed to create an MBR partition table and two partitions on the external USB drive using OSX' `fdisk` utility but I failed to find a way to format the existing partitions to ExFAT.

All the references I found so far point to `diskutil eraseDisk` or suggest using Windows or Linux for that, but I don't have access to bare-iron servers with these OS's and failed to access the unformatted USB drive from VirtualBox virtual machines on my laptop.

So, the question is - "Is there a way to execute the equivalent of `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1` on OS X?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format an ExFAT partition, unmount the partition and use `(sudo) newfs_exfat [options] /dev/disk*s*`. Check `man newfs_exfat` for the options.

The default FAT-size is 32bit, so you don't have to (or more precisely: you can't easily) specify the -F option.

Typically the Terminal commands should look like this:

```
diskutil list #to get the disk identifier of the exFAT partition
diskutil unmount /dev/diskxsy
sudo newfs_exfat -v Name /dev/diskxsy
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `diskutil` directly:

```
diskutil eraseVolume ExFat NewVolume /dev/diskXsY
                     |     |
                     ^ Format of partition
                           ^ Name of the new volume
```

You can also re-partition a whole disk all in one command:

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/diskX 2 MBR \
        ExFAT NewVolumeA 100M \     |
        ExFAT NewVolumeB R          |
        |     |          |          ^ Partition scheme, can be GPT or APM too
        ^ Format of partition
              ^ Name of the new volume
                         ^ Size of the volume, R means the rest.
```

Comment: strange that the partition is greyed out in the UI, but works via `diskuil` - thanks!